# Is there any simulator with OpenFlow support?

Tags: networking, simulator, openflow

I want to simulate OpenFlow to check its performance and efficiency in certain framework. How can I do that without using actual openflow enabled switches?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mininet, it's a openflow network prototyping tool that used openVSwitch. Mininet allows you to create large network topologies and simulate traffic.

Answer (score 3):

To do performance testing or in general research in Software Defined Networking field you have several options for network simulator & emulator:

1) [Mininet](http://mininet.org/)  (Emulator; Learning curve: Easy; Open source)

2) [Estinet](http://www.estinet.com/products.php) (Simulator & Emulator; Learning curve: Moderate; Proprietary)

3) [ns-3](http://www.nsnam.org/) (Simulator; Learning curve: Difficult; Open source)

Answer (score 1):

Mininet, as mentioned should be your best shot. http://mininet.github.com/

Its strong points are:

- active development
- very active mailing list
- preconfigured Ubuntu VM available
- supports other distributions, too

Go vote on the area 51 proposal to make it a stackexchange site!!! http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44914/openflow

I am in the process of building a Mininet installer for Fedora. It installs on a full install, once I get it to run completely and on a minimal install I will ask it to be forged back into mininet's trunk.